# What are the VID and PID for the Maker Pi RP2040 when connected by USB to PC

Tags: usbserial, rp2040

I have looked but cannot find these referenced currently - I have also asked on the cytron.io web site.

*I eventually found these (as well as the github reply) in the Datasheet at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DJASwxgbattM37V4AIlJVR4pxukq0up25LppA8-z_AY/edit*

*USB VID & PID (CircuitPython & Arduino Core)*

```
VID - 0x2E8A
PID - 0x1000_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may refer to this for RP2040's VID and PID https://github.com/raspberrypi/usb-pid

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote a little Python (PySerial) script and printed out the VID and PID, which are:

VID = 0x2E8A # 11914 decimal
PID = 0x1000 # 4096 decimal

I'm hoping these are fixed values...